# Want to display stored name/value data in intent to new activity screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am semi-ok with the understanding of how you store and retrieve data through intents, what I am not sure about however is the code implementation. What I want to accomplish is to pass stored data (name/value pairs and a bundle object) to my ThirdActivity class from MainActivity class. Here is a snippet what i have attempted thus far (which when the user clicks on the a3button it just displays a blank page with no string):

**MainActivity from which I want to store data to send to ThirdActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button a2_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a2_button);
        a2_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent a2intent = new Intent("com.tester.lab.x");
               startActivityForResult(a2intent, 1);
            }
        });

        Button a3_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a3_button);
        a3_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent a3intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ThirdActivity.class);

                a3intent.putExtra("greeting","my Name");
                startActivity(a3intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ThirdActivity:**

```
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        getIntent().getStringExtra("greeting");

    }
}
```

How would I display the string "my Name" once the user clicks ThirdActivity button? Any help is wonderful, thanks!

Comment: you have to set that value in TextView

Comment: Please use good variable names and follow some conventions like camel case.

Comment: `How would I display the string "my Name"` same way as any other string.  There is no difference. Any `String` is a `String`

Answer (score 1):

Everything is good, just add `String` type for value that you are getting and use this `String` as you want (to show in `TextView` else..):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_textView_id);

    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("greeting");
    text.setText(value);
}
```

Or by using `Button`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_textView_id);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);

    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("greeting");
           text.setText(value);
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Then how do you display that string to the screen?

Comment: check my code, use a textview to show the string. Add a textview to your activity_third layout and initiate the textview and add string to it

Comment: @skoteinos, did you find this helpful ?